DataTables Row Not Found After Searching For It A Second Time
I'm in the process of developing a webform using Bootstrap5 and DataTables to let users 1) search for students, 2) select a student, 3) edit the student, and then 4) search for other students.  Steps 1, 2 and 3 are working great.
In summary the steps are:

Use Bootstrap to collect the search fields
Display returned records into a datatable, along with a button in each row to select a student
When the user selects a student/row, copy the information into a second table (non-DataTable) and let them edit that student.
After the edits are done, the user should be able to enter new search data and repeat the above process.

As mentioned, after entering new search data the DataTable is destroyed and repopulated with no issues.  It's when the user tries to select a student/row to move down to the second table that the error pops up, stating it cannot find that row.
I've seen a couple of solutions to this issue and from what I can tell I'm doing exactly what the solutions say I need to do, so I'm not sure why mine isn't working.  Below are some screen shots so you can see the actual app and error I'm getting. Below that I created a code snippet that is not working perfectly, BUT it is recreating the error.

Below is the snippet.  To test and get the error:

Click Search
Select any of the three students (it **should populate in the second table but it's not...but don't worry about that)
Click Search again.
Select one of the students again -- boom the error happens.



function get_activeStudentSearch() {
  //If the datatable has already been initialized we need to destroy it and rebuild it
  if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#srchResults')) {
    $('#srchResults').DataTable().clear().destroy();
  }

  var studs = [{
    enrollmentID: "1234",
    lastName: "jones",
    firstName: "matt"
  }, {
    enrollmentID: "5678",
    lastName: "jones",
    firstName: "matt"
  }, {
    enrollmentID: "9012",
    lastName: "jones",
    firstName: "matt"
  }]

  $('#saveEnrollmentID').text("");
  $('#saveLastName').text("");
  $('#saveFirstName').text("");

  var dt = $(srchResults).DataTable({
    sorting: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    scrollY: '35vh',
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'B>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
    buttons: [
      'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'print'
    ],
    data: studs,
    columns: [{
        defaultContent: '<input type="button" class="select" value="Select"/>',
      },
      {
        data: "enrollmentID",
      },
      {
        data: "lastName",
      },
      {
        data: "firstName",
      },
    ],
  })

  $('#srchResults tbody').on('click', '.select', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    
    console.log(dt.row(row).data().enrollmentID);
    
    $('#saveEnrollmentID').text(dt.row(row).data().enrollmentID);
    $('#saveLastName').text(dt.row(row).data().lastName);
    $('#saveFirstName').text(dt.row(row).data().firstName);
  });
}
.srchHeaderCSS {
  font-size: x-small;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.3/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
      <div class="row mx-auto">
        <div id="srchButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" onclick="get_activeStudentSearch();">Search</div>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="divSearchTable" class="table-responsive" style="width: 99%">
      <table id="srchResults" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="srchHeaderCSS">enrollmentID</th>
            <th class="srchHeaderCSS">Last Name</th>
            <th class="srchHeaderCSS">First Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="h6"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div id="divSaveTable" class="table-responsive" style="width: 99%">
      <table id="saveResults" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
          <tr ">
                            <th></th>
                            <th class="srchHeaderCSS " >enrollmentID</th>
                            <th class="srchHeaderCSS ">Last Name</th>
                            <th class="srchHeaderCSS ">First Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="h6 ">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="button " class="Save " value="Select "/><input type="button " class="Cancel " value="Cancel "/></td>
                            <td id="saveEnrollmentID " ></td>
                            <td id="saveLastName "></td>
                            <td id="saveFirstName "></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



As always, I truly appreciate any help that you can spare!!
